# WPF ProgressBar doesn't show progress

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, progress-bar

I am confused by WPF ProgressBar. Here is the code I have written to display it:

```
<ProgressBar Height="31" Margin="15" Name="progressBar" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" IsIndeterminate="True" />
```

As I know this is enough to make it work. But it doesn't work in my project. I mean when I show window (Popup actually as it's xbap project) progressbar doesn't show any animation, however it is visible.

There are no background threads yet, UI thread is not blocked.

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you changed the default style of the ProgressBar?

Comment: Does it work in Design time ?

Comment: As you said yourself, this is supposed to be working, and it indeed works as i tested it just now. Since this is the case it should be apparent that your context is at fault here, sadly you did not provide any code for that.

Comment: What you have shown only shows how you have setup the progress bar so that it shows up on screen. You should provide some code showing how you are updating it (I assume this is what you want, your question is unclear)

Answer (score 4):

> There are no background threads yet, UI thread is not blocked.

I think you have that exactly wrong, and that's your problem.  You have no background threads, and thus your UI thread *is* blocked.  If your method that updates the progress bar is running on the UI thread (which it is, if you're not running it on a background thread), updates to the progress bar won't appear until the method is done running and control is returned to the Dispatcher.

You need to run your long-running method on a background thread using a `BackgroundWorker`, and update the progress bar by raising and handling its `ProgressChanged` event.  The event handler runs on the UI thread, and can update UI objects.

Comment: right. Check out more - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956902/are-background-thread-really-helpful-if-were-updating-our-gui-regularly

Answer (score 0):

It may use windows theme, in which indeterminate progress bars are not shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these codes

```
        ProgressBar test=new ProgressBar();
        Duration dr = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timespan));
        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation(determination, dr);
        test.IsIndeterminate = false;
        test.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        test.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, da);
```

If you want the ProgressBar work,you should create an Animation instance,and set it to the ProgressBar.May it help!